# How to transition UIView background color with wipe animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, optimization, uiview

**Background:**

I have a `UIView` that has a `UIColor.yellow` background:

```swift
let myView = UIView()
let myViewColor = UIColor.yellow
myView.backgroundColor = myViewColor
view.addSubview(myView)
```

**Question:**

How can I smoothly animate the transition of a `UIView` to have a `UIColor.blue` background with a wiping animation?

**Example:**

Here's an example mockup of a wipe animation created in Keynote:

[image: e]

Comment: One possible solution is to add a full frame yellow view at the bottom of the subviews to mimic a background. Then set the actual background color of your view to blue and animate the fake yellow background view off screen (removing it from the view hierarchy in the animation completion handler).

Comment: There is no built-in "wipe a new background color" effect. You can do this (as Geoff said) by animating a new view into place... Or, you can also do this with layer frame / size animation... Or, you *could* also do this with a gradient layer animation. Which approach to take depends on what else you might be wanting to do with this view.

Comment: Thanks Geoff, DonMag. Yes, I did have in mind animating an additional view, but was hoping not to do that. It’s possible to have a dissolve animation from one color to another color with `UIView.animateWithDuration`, so I was hoping there were other basic effects built in. A layer frame size animation or gradient layer animation sound interesting. The view will only be having a wipe animation applied to it, no other changes. There is also a `CISwipeTransition` that might be useful. I’m looking for a simple optimized method.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick example of **one** way to do this...

We'll use a `UIView` **extension**, which will:

- create a new `UIView` with the new background color
- add that as a subview at Zero so it's behind any other subviews
- position it to start off to the left
- animate it into place
- on completion, set the original view's background to the new background color, and remove the "temporary" view

So, the extension looks like this:

```
extension UIView {
    func wipeBackground(to newColor: UIColor, duration: Double) {
        let clips = self.clipsToBounds
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        let tempView = UIView(frame: bounds.offsetBy(dx: -bounds.width, dy: 0.0))
        tempView.backgroundColor = newColor
        insertSubview(tempView, at: 0)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                tempView.frame.origin.x = 0.0
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.backgroundColor = newColor
                tempView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.clipsToBounds = clips
            })
        }
    }
}
```

and an example view controller:

```
class WipeExampleVC: UIViewController {
    
    let testView = UIView()
    
    var colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue, .systemYellow
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        
        // let's add a label as a subview of testView
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Test View"
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 50.0, weight: .bold)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        testView.addSubview(label)

        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
            testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        testView.backgroundColor = nextColor()
    }
    func nextColor() -> UIColor {
        let c = colors.removeFirst()
        colors.append(c)
        return c
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let newC = nextColor()
        testView.wipeBackground(to: newC, duration: 1.0)
    }
    
}
```

When running, each tap (anywhere) will "wipe" to the new color:

[image]

Note: this is ***EXAMPLE CODE ONLY!!!*** - it is not intended to be "production ready." For example, if you call it again before the animation is finished, you'll get weird results.

Also, it could be easily modified to include wipe direction (top-down, right-left, etc).

Comment: Thanks, DonMag. I will give this a try. I will also experiment with a gradient layer animation.